# How to get paragraphs within a div to pop up side by side using flex?

Tags: css

I am trying to figure out how to get p tags within a div to pop up side by side and display somewhat like a table, but using flex instead of any floats.

```
        <div class="summary">
           <img src="life.jpg" alt="Life's great">
           <div>
              <div>
                 <p>Chapter 1:</p>
                 <p>0-10</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                 <p>Chapter 2:</p>
                 <p>11-20</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                 <p>Chapter 3:</p>
                 <p>21-30</p>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
```

So the output should look something along these lines, except I will have borders and such to design a box around it. I have to use flex which is throwing me off.

Chapter 1: 0-10

Chapter 2: 11-20

Chapter 3: 21-30

Answer (score 1):

Should just be as easy as applying `display: flex` on the container you want to have flex-laid out children within and giving a little margin.  The snippet below lays out the markup in the manner you showed in your question. It uses terrible selectors, but I didn't want to change your HTML structure at all.  However, I'd recommend putting classes on elements you wish to target so that you can avoid using element names as selectors.

```css
.summary > div > div {
  display: flex;
}

.summary > div > div > p:first-child {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="summary">
   <img src="life.jpg" alt="Life's great">
   <div>
      <div>
         <p>Chapter 1:</p>
         <p>0-10</p>
      </div>
      <div>
         <p>Chapter 2:</p>
         <p>11-20</p>
      </div>
      <div>
         <p>Chapter 3:</p>
         <p>21-30</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem-- please remember to upvote/accept the answer if it worked for you.  Welcome to Stack Overflow!